# How to track ALL the dependencies of a module in a Java project?

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq

As part of the optimization of a multi-application project, I have to update some RabbitMQ-related dependencies so that every application has the exact same versions, in the 'pom.xml' files. The problem is that RabbitMQ relies on other modules such as SLF4J and I guess there are other ones which I do not know and cannot straigthforwardly pinpoint. My question : is there a solution to quickly identify them all ? I am using IntelliJ as the IDE, maven for the dependency management and Git for version control.

Comment: You can generate an effective pom, there you can see all dependencies and which versions are being used. I think for IntelliJ its right click on pom.xml > Maven > Show effective POM

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html (`mvn dependency:list`)

Comment: Or use `mvn dependency:tree` if you want a tree view.